# What is the best practice to position an element-float or positioning?

Tags: css-float, css-position

First I should admit that I'm a beginner and the question might seem awkward to most of you, sorry for that.

My question is - what is the best practice (float or position) to position an element in a 2 or multi column layout assuming the design wont break apart after zooming an website?

I searched through this site and discovered some posts concerning this issue but those are 4/5years old and I could not come out with any conclusion.

Looking forward to have your expert views....
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its really based on how you want your element to be positioned or placed within the page.

**CSS Position:**
You should be choosing css positions to place your element if you wish the element to appear on top or bottom of any other elements and also if you wish to animate those.

Positioned element does not care for siblings placement.

**Floats:**
For creating columns, having content aligned to left or right and adjust to its adjacent siblings - you should use CSS floats.

Let us say, you have an image and bunch of texts, you should use floats if you wish to wrap texts around image. If image is not present then texts would cover the space. This wont happen in case of css positions.